# how to insert MSN Maps into my application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I want to insert MSN maps into my Asp.net application but I can't find sufficient stuff on this when I googled. "How to link MSN maps" link in this page is no more working. "http://www.mapblast.com/%28iniifwbwxwg54arnwwog3waq%29/DirectionsFind.aspx" can someone suggest any solution to insert only MSN maps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [**Bing** maps API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/). Developer articles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545001.aspx).